# How to run an aspnet core website built in Release locally with https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, .net-5

I am developing an asp net core website and using `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

When I start the website in debug from VS, I can browse it fine in https from `https://localhost:5001/`.

However, if I build it in Release and then run the executable, when I try to browse the website from `https://localhost:5001/` I am getting this, certainly related to a certificate problem:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte* pbCiphertext, UInt32 cbCiphertext, Byte*     pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, UInt32 cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 ciphertext, ArraySegment`1     additionalAuthenticatedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean     allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors,     Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)
10:40:47||0HM8IV1M7U2V2:00000005|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware|WRN|Error unprotecting the session cookie.
```

What do I have to do to be able to browse my website locally while running the executable compiled in Release?

Comment: So your project is built against .NET Framework (`[.net]`), .NET Core (`[.net-core]`), _and_ .NET 5 (`[.net-5]`)? Interesting...

Comment: I used .NET 5 for this

Comment: I've removed the other misleading tags from your question for you.

Comment: Is there a missing certificate in the release build

Comment: Hi @Neil. there are config file, exe, dlls and pdbs but no certificate I believe. How to generate one?

Comment: Could you please share the startup.cs codes? It seems that you don't bind the certificate when running this asp.net core application. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ssltls-protocols) and this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos).